# How to remove element from ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have added data into `ArrayList` and now want to update that list be deleting some element from it.

I have element something like 1,2,3,4 in `ArrayList` of type `CartEntry`.

Code :

```
ArrayList<CartEntry> items = new ArrayList<CartEntry>();

public void remove(int pId)
{
    System.out.println(items.size());

    for(CartEntry ce : items)
    {
        if(ce.getpId() == pId)
        {
            items.remove(ce);
            //System.out.println(items.get(1));             
        }
    }   
    items.add(new CartEntry(pId));
}
```

CartEntry Code :

```
public long getpId() {
    return pId;
}
```

Constructor :

```
public CartEntry(long pId) {
    super();
    this.pId = pId;     
}
```

when I am trying this code it gives me an error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

Here pId is the argument that specify that item should be deleted from items.
Suppose I want to delete item that have 2 data then what will I have to do ?

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Don't remove without iterator. This is dangerous.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Sir I have posted exception which I got and How to implement iterator ?

Comment: why are you adding the CartEntry again "items.add(new CartEntry(pId));" in the remove function

Comment: Just iterate the list in the reverse order for(int i=items.count; i <=0; i--)

Comment: @ray: there's no real reason to do that, an Iterator works just fine:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are facing `ConcurrentModificationException`  because you are  doing two operations on the same `list` at a time. i.e looping and removing  same time.

Inorder to avoid this situation use Iterator,which guarantees you to remove the element from list safely .

A simple example looks like

```
Iterator<CartEntry> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().getpId() == pId) {
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Superb Answer.. Everyone's Answer Are Same and Your One line extra Made my code easy and workable and that is a simple `break`. Thanx.

Comment: @user2659972ღ: the break is not necessary and only realy useful if you know that no two `CartEntry` objects will have the same id.

Comment: @JoachimSauer -Yes sir but If I don't use `break` and delete item then it works but after that I got the error same as above but problem item is removed. SO that's why `break` make it done for me.

Comment: @user2659972ღ: if you get the exception without the `break` then you're still using `items.remove()` as opposed to `it.remove()`!

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two problems with your code:

1. you call `remove` on the collection you iterate over, that will cause a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) if you continue iterating after the `remove`.

   There are two ways to fix this:

   - stop iterating after you found the object you want to remove (just add a `break` or a `return`) *or*
   - switch from the enhanced for-loop to using [an `Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and [its `remove` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).
2. you **add** an element in your `remove` method, that's probably not what you want.

So I'd use this code (this assumes that there is only ever one `CartEntry` with a given id in the list):

```
public void remove(int pId)
{
    for(CartEntry ce : items)
    {
        if(ce.getpId() == pId)
        {
            items.remove(ce);
            return;
        }
    }   
}
```

If the assumption with the unique id is not correct, then you'll need to use the `Iterator` approach:

```
public void remove(int pId)
{
    Iterator<CartEntry> it = items.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        CartEntry ce = it.next();
        if(ce.getpId() == pId)
        {
            it.remove();
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have created an Arraylist of type `carEntry`. So you need to create an Iterator of type `CarEntry`

```
Iterator<CarEntry> it =  items.iterator();    
while(it.hasNext())
{
   if(it.next().getPId == PId)
   it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement .equals in CartEntry and then use ArrayList.remove(CartEntry) or loop through your array list, find the item with some condition, mark the index, and call ArrayList.remove(index) -- AFTER the loop

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
public void remove(int pId){

Iterator<CartEntry> it = items.iterator();

 while(it.hasNext()) {
    CartEntry entry = it.next();
    if (entry.getpId() == pId) {
        it.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `enhanced-for`(or for each) loop for iterating over an `Expression` which is a subtype of `Iterable<E>` or raw `Iterable`, basically equivalent to the following form:

```
  for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {   
      VariableIdentifiers_opt TargetType Identifier = (TargetType) #i.next();
         Statement
   }
```

This is clearly stated in [**jls 14.14.2. The enhanced for statement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) section.

For your context the `Expression` is an `ArrayList`. the iterators returned by `ArrayList`'s iterator  method is fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

use an `Iterator` instead and use it's own `remove()` method:

```
  Iterator<E>iterator = list.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
    if(iterator.next().equals(E))
      iterator.remove();
```