# Removing specific items in Arraylist

Tags: java

I am struggling with removing items from my arraylist. More specifically, I have two arraylists, being persons and vulcanos. Both are located in a grid. Each time step, people can move or not (this happens randomly, to the adjecant cells), while volcanos are static during the whole simulation. Volcanos can erupt or not. This is determined by a probability defined by the user. When at a certain timestep a person is located at the same cell as an erupting volcano, this person dies. But I don't know how I can remove that specific person from my array. So far I got the following (is repeated for each time step).

```
for (int j = 0; j < persons.size(); j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < volcanos.size(); k++) {
        if ((persons.get(j).getXCoordPerson()) == (volcanos.get(k).getXCoordVolcano())
                && (persons.get(j).getYCoordPerson()) == (volcanos.get(k).getYCoordVolcano())
                && (volcanos.get(k).getEruptionStatus() == true)) {
            // all persons being on the same cell as an erupting volcano die
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an `Iterator`, code sample here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116710/how-to-remove-element-from-arraylist

Comment: You might find it easier to simply mark the people dead till the end of your simulation. Using the for each loop syntax will also make your code a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `Iterator` too:

```
for(Iterator<Person> personIterator = persons.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Person person = personIterator.next();
    for(Volcano volcano : volcanos) {
        if(volcano.getEruptionStatus() && 
           volcano.getYCoordVolcano() == person.getYCoordPerson() &&
           volcano.getXCoordVolcano() == person.getXCoordPerson()) {
               personIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, you are using the iterator to do the removing, leaving the `ArrayList` in the state you want as a side effect of the loops.

One thing to watch out for is that you do not modify the list of people during this loop or you will end up with a `ConcurrentModificationException`. I'm assuming you have one single thread operating, and that this is for schoolwork or something similar. If you were doing this in the real-world, you would have to account for the fact that both lists (people and volcanos) could be changing at any time.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine now. It's indeed for a schoolwork, and I am a java newbie :) Is their any way to print the deleted objects? That would be handy to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to mark your people as dead or harmed(etc.) or add them to another list. Then delete them after loop like

```
persons.removeAll(deadPeople);
```

Comment: Err, yes, he can, especially when looping the way he does. He'd better loop in reverse order to avoid the employees to change position during the iteration, though. He could also use an Iterator to remove persons while looping.

Comment: Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration!

Comment: Otherwise, he will get ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: You don't understand how a list and its iterator work, and why you get a ConcurrentModificationException. Just test this code: http://ideone.com/zn5SjZ

Comment: @azat the problem with what you are saying is that it is only correct if you are using the iterator to go through the list. He is looping through the lists by index

Comment: I tell you that, if he would use iterator as @Todd says, it will be ok. But he is using looping throught index, so if he wants to remove element by index during looping, he will get ConcurrentModificationException!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind working with `Iterable` instead of `List`, and if you don't mind taking dependency on Guava, then why not use `Iterables`?

```
Iterable<Person> filtered = Iterables.filter(persons, new Predicate<Person>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Person person) {
                for (Volcano v : volcanos) {
                    if (v.getEruptionStatus() && 
                        v.getXCoordVolcano() == person.getXCoordPerson() && 
                        v.getYCoordVolcano() == person.getYCoordPerson()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This will filter out all dead `Persons`, and will leave `filtered` with only living people

Comment: And a nice optimization you can do is keep a `MultiMap` from the x coord (or y) of your volcanos (they are static so it will never change) to the volcanos withs that x coord, and that should speed up your filtering (though not in the worst case). You can even map from the coordinates to the volcanos, which would make it even faster, but would require changing your code and implementing hash code for two ints.